# Retrieve related field's object in GET requests, otherwise use only ID of the object in POST, PUT, DELETE etc

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two serializers. The 'category' field in the Article is a ForeignKey.

I want to retrieve category object completely when I do a GET request. And I want to use only ID of the category when I do a POST, PUT or DELETE request.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'slug')

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'slug', 'body', 'category')
        depth = 1
```

If I add the "depth = 1" property to the Meta class, then I'm getting the category object. It's OK.

But, if I try to add new Article (via POST request) I'm getting this error:

```
IntegrityError at /api/articles
NOT NULL constraint failed: panel_article.category_id
```

If I try with defining a CategorySerializer field, instead of use 'depth' property like this:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'slug', 'body', 'category')
```

I'm getting this error due to category field:

```
"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
```

I guess DRF is trying to create new category, when I try to create a new Article.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common problem, every time when you want to change representation behavior you are free to use `to_representation` method of a serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'slug', 'body', 'category')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(ArticleSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['category'] = CategorySerializer(instance.category).data
        return representation
```

Comment: Oh, It works! Thank you, you saved my day. I guess there is not enough documentation about 'to_presentation'. There is?
Actually, I don't understand how it works... :(

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun DRF has a great docs, check this method explanation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer. And here http://www.cdrf.co/